# Determining the player that played the most games

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class that contains player numbers...

```
public class Game {
    public int blackPlayer { get; set; }
    public int whitePlayer { get; set; }
}
```

and a...

```
List<Game> games;
```

I want to know which player number occurs the most in the list (regardless if they played as black or white). Does anyone know a good LINQ expression this?

Comment: Apart from your original question, I find your naming schemes highly confusing. It took me quite a while to figure out that *black* actually means *playerNumberWhoWasBlack*.

Comment: I changed 'black' and 'white' to 'blackPlayer' and 'whitePlayer'.

Comment: can the white and black player be the same?

Comment: Francisco, blackPlayer != whiteplayer foreach element of the games list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should accomplish your goal:

```
var q = (from g in games
        from p in new[] {g.blackPlayer, g.whitePlayer}
        group p by p into pgroup
        orderby pgroup.Count() descending
        select new { Player = pgroup.Key,  Count =  pgroup.Count() }).FirstOrDefault();


Console.WriteLine("Player # {0} played {1} times which is the most", q.Player,  q.Count);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the ties.

```
List<int> mostFrequentPlayers = games.Select(g => g.blackPlayer)
  .Concat(games.Select(g => g.whitePlayer))
  .GroupBy(p => p) //into g
  .GroupBy(g => g.Count()) //into g2
  .OrderByDescending(g2 => g2.Key)
  .First()
  .SelectMany(g2 => g2, g => g.Key) //unpack g2 as g.Key
  .ToList();
```